# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text' python 2.7

Tags: string, python-2.7, proxy, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Ik there are many questions like this but the answers are all specific and can only fix the solution for the persons specific script.
I am currently trying to print a bunch of info from supremenewyork.com
from the uk website.  This script can succsesfully print all the info I want from supreme us but when I added the proxy script I starte to get alot of errors.
I know the prxy script works becuase I tested it on a small scipt and It was able to pull info that was on supreme uk and didnt exist on supreme us 
Here is my script.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

UK_Proxy1 = raw_input('UK http Proxy1: ')
UK_Proxy2 = raw_input('UK http Proxy2: ')

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://' + UK_Proxy1 + '',
        'https': 'http://' + UK_Proxy2 + '',

}

categorys = ['jackets','shirts','tops_sweaters','sweatshirts','pants','shorts','t- shirts','hats','hats','bags','accessories','shoes','skate']
catNumb = 0
altArray = []
nameArray = []
styleArray = []

for cat in categorys:
    catStr = str(categorys[catNumb])
    cUrl = 'http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/' + catStr
    proxy_script = requests.get((cUrl.text), proxies=proxies)
    bSoup = BeautifulSoup(proxy_script, 'lxml')
    print('\n*******************"'+ catStr.upper() + '"*******************\n')
    catNumb += 1
for item in bSoup.find_all('div', class_='inner-article'):
    url = item.a['href']
    alt = item.find('img')['alt']
    req = requests.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com' + url)
    item_soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
    name = item_soup.find('h1', itemprop='name').text
    style = item_soup.find('p', itemprop='model').text
    print alt +(' --- ')+ name +(' --- ')+ style

    altArray.append(alt)
    nameArray.append(name)
    styleArray.append(style)

print altArray
print nameArray
print styleArray
```

I am getting this error when I execute the script

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text' with the error pointing towards the

proxy_script = requests.get((cUrl.text), proxies=proxies)

i recently added this to the script which sorta fixed it... It was able to print the category's but no info between them. Which (I NEED)  it just printed  ****************jackets**************, ****shirts******, etc.... here is what I changed

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# make sure proxy is http and port 8080
UK_Proxy1 = raw_input('UK http Proxy1: ')
UK_Proxy2 = raw_input('UK http Proxy2: ')

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://' + UK_Proxy1 + '',
        'https': 'http://' + UK_Proxy2 + '',

}

categorys = ['jackets','shirts','tops_sweaters','sweatshirts','pants','shorts','t-shirts','hats','bags','accessories','shoes','skate']
catNumb = 0
altArray = []
nameArray = []
styleArray = []

for cat in categorys:
    catStr = str(categorys[catNumb])
    cUrl = 'http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/' + catStr
    proxy_script = requests.get(cUrl, proxies=proxies).text
    bSoup = BeautifulSoup(proxy_script, 'lxml')
    print('\n*******************"'+ catStr.upper() + '"*******************\n')
    catNumb += 1
for item in bSoup.find_all('div', class_='inner-article'):
    url = item.a['href']
    alt = item.find('img')['alt']
    req = requests.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com' + url)
    item_soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
    name = item_soup.find('h1', itemprop='name').text
    style = item_soup.find('p', itemprop='model').text
    print alt +(' --- ')+ name +(' --- ')+ style

    altArray.append(alt)
    nameArray.append(name)
    styleArray.append(style)
```

print altArray
print nameArray
print styleArray

I put .text at the end and it worked sorta.... How do i fix it so it prints the info I want???

Comment: You are defining cUrl to be a string: `cUrl = 'http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/' + catStr`. That string does not have a `text` attribute. Try running `requests.get(cUrl` instead.

Comment: @patrick that does not work I get this error when I run the script without the without the text:          bs4/__init__.py", line 192, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Comment: Please don't add new questions to your original question after you solve your first one. Have a look at [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions).

Comment: @KeyurPotdar bruh..... the first one hasnt been solved

Comment: I get it. SO **is** for getting help. Just follow the rules and you will get all the help you want. Posting a new question is the best approach here. Also, it'll be better if you rollback your question to the first revision (someone else might do it later).

Comment: Your first problem **has** been solved. You were using `.text` at the wrong position (as mentioned in the comments and the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss smt. Your    cUrl is a string type, not request type. I guess you want:
   proxy_script = requests.get(cUrl, proxies=proxies).text

Comment: I added you script and it printed *******************"JACKETS"*******************


*******************"SHIRTS"*******************


*******************"TOPS_SWEATERS"*******************     but no info inside???   usually it prints the category with the item code, name, and color inside but it was just a blank space

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^@dx247^